# Just downloaded the Scala Lift chat application and use the instructions to run it, but it fails

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I cloned the project from:

```
https://github.com/dpp/simply_lift.git
```

Then I followed the instructions which state:

```
Change directories into the chat directory and type sbt update ~jetty-run.
```

SBT fetches dependencies, and then I get this:

```
[error] Not a valid command: jetty-run
[error] Expected '/'
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: jetty-run (similar: run)
[error] jetty-run
[error]
```

Now what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In versions of SBT newer than 0.10.0, `~jetty-run` has been removed in favour of:

```
container:start
container:stop
deployment // compiles the changes made while jetty is running.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should've used sbt from the packaged archive (`./sbt`). Instead of a system-wide SBT (which may be new).

Anyway, I suggest to use use the new SBT and everything new, too. This is the official and good starting point for a project: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/
(personally I use it and I'm cool with how it works)

Comment: I did use the packaged ./sbt and it still failed.